# Less dark energy and more dark matter

Tags: physics, alternate-reality

What if in an alternate universe, the amount of dark dark energy is 12% and the amount of dark matter is 72%. How would this effect the physic of that universe?

Comment: As it is now it looks like a question for physics_stackexchange

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a) too broad and b) Dark matter/dark Energy is still only a theory and hasn't been proven yet. We can't even prove how it affects our own universe's physics, how do you expect us to do calculations for a new universe?

Answer (score 2):

If this happened, then the universe would collapse under its own gravity.

In the present universe, expansion is caused by dark energy, while matter, both visible and dark, pulls it together. With the balance in our universe, dark energy is more powerful than matter, so the universe will endlessly expand. However, you are reversing this balance, so the opposite will happen.